# Do photons have "friction" passing through fluctuating gravitational waves?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, photons, friction

In the 1998 biography, A Beautiful Mind, by Sylvia Nasar, John Nash is said to have entered Einstein's office to discuss his ideas that photons have friction.

> Nash had an idea about "gravity, friction, and radiation," as he later recalled. The friction he was thinking of was the friction that a particle, say a photon, might encounter as it moved through space due to its fluctuating gravitational field interacting with other gravitational fields. Nash had given his hunch enough thought to spend much of the meeting at the blackboard scribbling equations. Soon, Einstein and Kemeny were standing at the blackboard as well. The discussion lasted the better part of an hour. But in the end all that Einstein said, with a kindly smile, was "You had better study some more physics, young man." Nash did not immediately take Einstein's advice and he never wrote a paper on his idea. His youthful foray into physics would become a lifetime interest-though, like Einstein's search for the unified field, it would not be especially fruitful. Many decades later, however, a German physicist published a similar idea.

The references for this section show it was all Nash's recollections, as told to Harold Kuhn, years later.

What was the similar idea published by the German physicist? Is it true that photons have friction or some other related property?

Comment: Just a caution. If you are looking for an explanation for the cosmological red shift, this cannot be it. It falls in the discredited category of tired light theories.

Comment: at that time elementary particles have not been discovered as such.  We now have the photon as an elementary partcle in quantum mechanical standard model of physics. it is a point particle, with zero mass, and the only thing that can happen when it interacts with fields is be redshifted or blue shifted,. What more, gravitational interactions at the quantum level are still under research.

Comment: The energy of photons contributes to the stress-energy tensor, so they would be affected by gravity, and this can also be see in gravitational lensing. They also lose energy when coming out of a gravitational well - gravitational redshift; this is kind of like 'friction'. (But everyday friction has very different properties I think.)